# Need to print rows of multidimensional array as columns

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

This is my program output:

```
Enter the size of 2D array: 
4
1   2   3   4   

5   6   7   8   

9   10  11  12  

13  14  15  16
```

and I need this instead:

```
1    12    5    16
2    11    6    15
3    10    7    14
4    9     8    13
```

I want the 2d array to be of size NxN where n is the integer inputted by the user. I want the first consecutive values to be stored in the even indexed columns from top to bottom and the next consecutive values to be stored in the odd indexed columns from bottom to top.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Lab6 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter the size of 2D array: ");
    System.out.println();
    int n = input.nextInt();

    int arr[][] = new int[n][n];

    int inc=1;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
        {
        arr[i][j]=inc;
        inc++;
        }
    }

    transpose(arr);

    // now let's print a two dimensional array in Java
    for (int[] a : arr) {
        for (int i : a) {
            System.out.print(i + "\t");
        }
        System.out.println("\n");

    }
}
public static int[][] transpose (int[][] array) {
      if (array == null || array.length == 0)//empty or unset array, nothing do to here
        return array;

      int width = array.length;
      int height = array[0].length;

      int[][] array_new = new int[height][width];

      for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
          array_new[y][x] = array[x][y];
        }
      }
      return array_new;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your transpose function returns `array_new` but you don't actually use that return value in your actual code

Answer (score 2):

As Sean pointed out in the comments, your `transpose()` function returns a new array but you are not capturing that and using it.  The original array remains unchanged, which is what you are displaying at the end.

Change:

```
transpose(arr);

// now let's print a two dimensional array in Java
for (int[] a : arr) {
```

To:

```
int[][] newArr = transpose(arr);

// now let's print a two dimensional array in Java
for (int[] a : newArr) {
```

Comment: This doesn't quite get the desired output with the unusual even/odd column usage rules...re-write your loops to accommodate that.  For loops don't always have to go up by one with `i++`, they could go up by two with `i=i+2`...!

Comment: To get your final desired product, I'd use two sets of nested for loops.  The first set iterating over the even columns, with the second set going over the odd columns.  The inner, nested for loops would go either from top to bottom, or bottom to top, as appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Try this out. It should do what you have described in the question.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter the size of 2D array: ");
    System.out.println();
    int n = input.nextInt();
    int arr[][] = new int[n][n];

    int inc=1;
    for(int j = 0; j < n; j += 2) {
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            arr[i][j]=inc++;
        }
    }
    for(int j = 1; j < n; j += 2) {
        for(int i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            arr[i][j]=inc++;
        }
    }

    // now let's print a two dimensional array in Java
    for (int[] a : arr) {
        for (int i : a) {
            System.out.print(i + "\t");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: Trey  the odd columns are supposed to go from bottom to top: "I want the first consecutive values to be stored in the even indexed columns from top to bottom and the next consecutive values to be stored in the odd indexed columns from bottom to top."

Comment: I have edited the answer to reflect the bottom to top on odd.